# Node positioning issue in Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I'm just starting out looking into Swift 3 - never coded before so I'm completely new to it all. Been looking at a really basic Node tutorial and have the following code:

```
class GameScene: SKScene {

    override func didMove(to view: SKView) {

        // SKLabelNode
        var exampleLabelNode = SKLabelNode(fontNamed: "Helvetica")
        exampleLabelNode.text = "Example Label Node!"
        exampleLabelNode.fontSize = 30
        exampleLabelNode.fontColor = SKColor.white
        exampleLabelNode.position = CGPoint(x: self.frame.size.width / 2, y: self.frame.size.height * 0.75)
        self.addChild(exampleLabelNode)

        // SKSpriteNode
        var exampleSpriteNode = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "myImage")
        exampleSpriteNode.size = CGSize(width: 180, height: 180)
        exampleSpriteNode.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 0.5)
        exampleSpriteNode.position = CGPoint(x: self.frame.size.width / 2, y: self.frame.size.height * 0.25)
        exampleSpriteNode.zPosition = 100
        exampleSpriteNode.name = "exampleName"
        self.addChild(exampleSpriteNode)

    }

}
```

It's meant to position *exampleLabelNode* centre and 3/4 at the top of the screen and *exampleSpriteNode* 1/4 at the bottom of the screen.

However its positioning *exampleSpriteNode* 3/4 to the top of the screen and half off to the right with the *exampleLabelNode* positioned off the screen.

The tutorial is for Swift 2, so is the positioning syntax etc different for Swift 3?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is happening because the default scene `anchorPoint` is (0.5, 0.5) meaning the centre of the scene. That's also the default `anchorPoint` for any node. That makes the point (x: 0, y: 0) at the centre of the scene.

I suggest you read more about this or ask questions to get a better understanding of it if you're having trouble.

**Official Apple Docs**

[SKSpriteNode anchorPoint](https://developer.apple.com/reference/spritekit/skspritenode/1519877-anchorpoint)

[SKScene anchorPoint](https://developer.apple.com/reference/spritekit/skscene/1519864-anchorpoint)

**Note:** The docs for the SKScene is incorrect when it says that the default value is (0, 0).

To solve your issue, you can add this line to the beginning of your `didMove(to view)`:

```
self.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)
```

This sets the scene `anchorPoint` to the bottom left of the scene, which used to be how it was (The tutorial is outdated).

Alternatively, you could redo the sprite placement now that you know how `anchorPoint` works. I suggest this because I find building games to be easier when building the scene from the centre outwards rather than from the bottom left corner.

Comment: I thought the line:

`exampleSpriteNode.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 0.5)`

was to set the centre point of the exampleSpriteNode when positioning it.

So am I right in thinking that positioning is made by using the centre of the screen as a default x:0, y:0 rather than the lower left?

Comment: @Bootfit It is. `anchorPoint` is a property that all nodes (including scenes) have. It decides which part of the node is the centre. The example you just wrote changes to anchorPoint of the node because it starts with `exampleSpriteNode.anchorPoint = ...`. My example changes the scene (self) because it starts with `self.anchorPoint = ...`

Comment: @Bootfit I don't understand what you're asking, but did adding the line do anything?

Comment: Thanks Nik - dropped your `self.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0) ` and so the code now works as it should.

But, you say the tutorial is outdated, so if I didn't drop your code in, how would I modify my code to bring it inline with the new way of doing things?

If I wanted to position _exampleSpriteName_ in the lower centre of the screen, what would I change? Hopefully I'll be able to work backwards and start to understand positioning and will be able to position _exampleLabelNode_ correctly.

Comment: @Bootfit You would just place nodes knowing that (0,0) is the centre. For example, CGPoint(x: 0, y: self.frame.size.height/4) would be where your example label would be placed (based on what you said in the question). To go below or left of centre on the scene, you would need to use negative x and y values. Your example sprite would be placed at CGPoint(x: 0, y: -self.frame.size.height/4)

Comment: Excellent - thanks Nik. I was playing around with negative values - didn't occur to me to put the '-' before self.frame.size.height.

Comment: Accepted and upvoted - I've not got enough rep yet for it to be publicly visible.